# Command + Delete inserts a tab at the start of the line for some reasons

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I want to delete everything from the point of the cursor to the front of line with Command + Delete on insert mode. So I wrote the following on `~/.vimrc`.

```
inoremap <D-Bs> <C-u>
```

But this inserts a tab at the front of the line, not delete.

I'm not even sure why, but how can I delete everything to the front of the line?

Here is the result of `:imap <d-bs>`.

[image]

And typing Control + U deletes to the front of the line on insert mode. Just the key remapping with `<D-Bs>` doesn't...

---

I'm still not sure why this happens, but launching vim without `~/.vimrc` (`$vim -u NONE`) still has this issue.

Adding `set backspace=indent,eol,start` doesn't work, either.

Comment: FWIW, My terminal doesn't even get command-backspace as anything other than backspace. In macvim, this worked just fine.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I found that in MacVim the command and delete works fine. Only when I launch vim on Terminal does it not work properly.